# How access Primefaces DataTable Rows from Java

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I want to get the different rows from a PrimeFaces DataTable Component in Java. I can find the DataTable from the ViewRoot by using findComponent. Now when i look into the Component (using Debugger) i can see 3 Children, the Children. These Children are the 3 Columns in the first Row of my DataTable, but i cant access the other rows.

My Table XHTML is structured like this: (Example)

```
<h:form id="form">
     <p:dataTable id="table" var="t">
          <p:column>
               <p:inputNumber id="inputOne" />
          </p:column>
          <p:column>
               <p:inputNumber id="inputTwo" />
          </p:column>
          <p:column>
               <p:inputNumber id="inputThree" />
          </p:column>
     </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

This is how i get the DataTable in my Java Code:

```
final DataTable table = (DataTable) getFacesContext().getViewRoot().findComponent("form:table");

table.getChildren(); // 3 Children, even if the DataTable got 10 Rows.
```

How can i access the other Rows in the DataTable? I only get the 3 Columns in the first Row as Children.

Tried to get as far as i can throught the debugger, but i can't find the other Rows / Components.

Comment: What about opposite way: prepare data model for table in Java and have full access to any field in any row?

Comment: The DataModel is much more complex and already implemented, i need only the Components in Java to set them "invalid" ( .setValid(false) ), to display them as invalid field. I cant use the validator tag because the validation is done by an external service.

Comment: Even if I don't have used this method it should work: You have to define a property in your backing bean of type org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable and then use the binding attribute of <p:dataTable />. Than in your backing bean throug this new property you can access the rows values. Please look at the DataTable doc to check the right method https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.0/org/primefaces/component/datatable/DataTable.html

Comment: The binding element works, but i still dont get the rows that i need. I only find the first row and the first columns. Got the same element like i got on my example.

Comment: I think there is an xyproblem here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I tried the Solution of @KDavid-Valerio, but got the same result like i got on my example.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use  `rowIndexVar="rowId"` attribute of p:dataTable. You can use it to pass the id of the selected row.

You can add a column with a link to make the row 'invalid':

```
<p:column>
   <h:commandLink action="#{managedBeanActionToMakeRowInvalid}">
     <f:param name="rowIndex" value="#{rowId}" />
   </h:commandLink>
</p:column>
```